# Angular display all the images in an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to display these images inside "image_url" array.
I used for loop but images are not visible.

```
Array - 
image_url: [
0: "https://xyz/16183424594601618342458.5021539.jpg"
1: "https://xyz/16183424594701618342458.579036.jpg"
2: "https://xyz/16183424594511618342458.4947538.jpg"
3: "https://xyz/16183424594661618342458.566865.jpg" ]

this.postImages = res.data.postdata.image_url;

<div class="" *ngFor="let images of postImages">
            <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
                <div class="items-center py-4">
                  <img class="side-image w-56 h-56 mr-4 bg-cover bg-no-repeat border"
                    [src]="images ? images : './assets/profile.svg'">
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
```

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems correct, make sure your image links are working.

Comment: sometimes when dealing with url string you need to sanitize them, do you get any error or warnings ?

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen No error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but it looks like your 1st item in the array is an numeric value and the second the actual url, have you tried using images[1]. You can verify this by looking at the compiled html to see what it prints out for src?

Comment: Most probably it's an artifact of copying the output of `console.log` statement. Most browsers print the array with their corresponding index.

Comment: True, agree see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Please declare a variable as a string array or any mention below

public postImages : any

public postImages : string[];

Might be a declaration there is an issue otherwise code working perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

It resolved when I added i=index.

```
<div class="" *ngFor="let images of postImages; let i = index">
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what actually fixed it. Did you change anything else?